# Finding a word in a string using only libraries iostream and cstring

Tags: c++

So i've got a string defined as a sentence with its spaces replaced with "*". For example:

```
suffix*i*am*using*stackoverflow*text1suffix*text2suffix
```

The first word of the sentence is the 'suffix'. What I need to do is separate the sentence into different words using strtok and then print every word **which ends in the suffix**. The output would be the following:

```
text1suffix, text2suffix
```

The tricky part is that I need to do this only by using libraries **iostream** and **cstring**.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    char s[256], t[256], *p, l, ok;

    strcpy(s, "suffix*i*am*using*stackoverflow*text1suffix*text2suffix");
    p = strtok(s, "*");
    strcpy(t, p);
    l = strlen(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, "*");

    while(p) {
        ok = 1;
        for(int i = strlen(p)-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(l-(strlen(p)-i) > 0) {} else break;
            if(p[i] == t[l-(strlen(p)-i)]) { }
            else { ok = 0; break; }
        }
        if(ok == 1) cout << "*" << p;

        p = strtok(NULL, "*");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What I did is check every single character(starting from the last one) and check if they are the same as in the first word.

The question is: Is there ANY way I could do this with fewer effort? Or is there any other way to solve this problem? I feel like my method isn't good.

Comment: `strcmp` might be helpful

Comment: Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: [here it is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp)

Comment: _"using libraries iostream"_ would replacing character classification for stream so it would treat * as space remove the need for `strtok`?

Comment: *Is there ANY way I could do this with fewer effort?* -- Yes -- scrap your `C` requirements and use idiomatic C++ using `std::string`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can't. This is a task from the romanian baccalaureate exam. It's a requirement to write code like that

Comment: This may be a better candidate for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Radu -- Well, you're learning `C` and not `C++`, just to warn you.  Not only do the `C` functions give it away that you're learning `C`, but the declaration of that `ok` variable to be an `char` instead of `bool` is another indication that the course you're taking is misnamed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know, but it's an obligatory course, and an official one. All the students from Romania take this same course, and without passing this exam I can't join universities or get a job.

Answer (score 0):

> The question is: Is there ANY way I could do this with fewer effort?

First, I highly recommend you use better naming convention for your variables.  Names such as `l` and `t` do not describe what they represent.  Something like this:

```
 char *suffix = strtok(s, "*");
 int suffixLength = strlen(suffix);
```

As to your inner `for` loop, there is no need to write such a loop, since the `strstr` function does the work of finding a string within a string.

`char *found = strstr(p, suffix);`

If this does not return `NULL`, then you can test to see whether the character beyond the found `"suffix"` string is a null-terminator, since you're dealing with null terminated strings.  If the character after the found suffix isn't `\0`, then you know the string does not end in the suffix string.

```
if ( found && *(found + suffixLength) == '\0') // the suffix must be found, and it must occur at the end of the string.
{
   // ends with the suffix string.
}
```

In addition, you are calling `strlen` multiple times on the same char buffer.  That is highly wasteful.

Given this information you should be able to put together a "better" loop without the unnecessary calls to `strlen`.